# Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, webstorm

I recently went in to app development and I am using WebStorm for my IDE on Windows 7.

I created a skeleton Phonegap/Cordova project and replaced all the css/js/html files from a project that was made on Visual Studios 15.
Assuming that only the appearance of the program would change, however I started getting this error:

> ERROR: Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try
>   setting setting it manually. Failed to find 'android' command in your
>   'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

I tryed some of the solutions i found online, like actually installing the android SDK and then adding `ANDROID_HOME` with a path to where i installed my sdk and adding `%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools` to `PATH`.
However this didn't work ether.

I am new to the website, so sorry if I am being to vague or my bad English, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your system environment variable add like this,In value give complete path to your JAVA sdk.It can work and also try this command in cmd

```
cordova platform update android
```

[image]